# Spring: Checking if given endpoint exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Just like in title. I wonder, if there is simple way to check if given path can traslate to (API) endpoint that exists in any controller.

I have a custom filter with highest precedence and I want to return 404 status code if given request won't yield any results (endpoint doesn't exist).

Comment: Are you creating a client to a service or are you hosting the service and want to check your own endpoints before handling a request?

Comment: @KevinBayes second one. I'm adding a filter in which I want to check if endpoint exists (sending 404 if not, sending other status code or continuing down the filter chain otherwise)

Comment: Okay I added a sample of how I would go about doing it with spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) class, particularly its [`getHandlerMethods`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html#getHandlerMethods--) method.

From the docs:

> `public Map<T,HandlerMethod> getHandlerMethods()`
>
> Return a (read-only) map with all mappings and HandlerMethod's.

For `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, `T` is `RequestMappingInfo`.

From [`RequestMappingInfo` docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html):

> Encapsulates the following request mapping conditions:
>
> 1. PatternsRequestCondition
> 2. RequestMethodsRequestCondition
> 3. ParamsRequestCondition
> 4. HeadersRequestCondition
> 5. ConsumesRequestCondition
> 6. ProducesRequestCondition
> 7. RequestCondition (optional, custom request condition)

And from [`HandlerMethod` docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html):

> Encapsulates information about a handler method consisting of a method and a bean. Provides convenient access to method parameters, method return value, method annotations.

---

If you want to do this from a filter bean, you could just autowire `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean to it:

```
@Component
public class MyFilterBean extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappings;

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you how do I obtain these from Filter/OncePerRequestFilter classes?

Comment: @TrynkiewiczMariusz Sure, just autowire `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do this then you need to create a filter that has the RequestMappingHandlerMapping as an attribute. Something like this:

```
 public class AllHandlersList extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    public AllHandlersList(RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping) {
        this.requestMappingHandlerMapping = requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            //Add you own logic here ot handle the request your way. 
            System.out.println(requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Then you need to register it. I see you use spring boot so you can add this to your java config:

```
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public FilterRegistrationBean listHandlers(RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping) {
        FilterRegistrationBean register = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        register.setFilter(new AllHandlersList(requestMappingHandlerMapping));
        register.setName("handlerListFilter");
        register.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"/"}));
        register.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return register;
    }
```

References:
API Docs
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html

Spring Release Notes
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-31-vs-30