# How to return a status code of 400 when path is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot REST application. I need to return a status code of 400 bad request when the path does not exists. Consider:

```
This is a good url
localhost:8080/mypath?name=test

Bad Path (return status 400)
localhost:8080/mybadpath?name=test
```

How can I do this using spring boot

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning 404? :)

Comment: which version of spring boot?

Comment: @Deadpool its spring boot 2.1.3

Comment: i tried with `2.1.0` it works for me try my answer @Luke101

Comment: @TheLostMind actually, I must do it. The choice is not up to me.

Comment: @Luke101 - In that case Deadpool's answer should do it

Comment: There aren't any answers (at the moment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This works for spring boot-2.1.3** by implementing `ErrorController`

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

private static final String PATH = "/error";

@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
public ResponseEntity<String> error(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("");

}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return PATH;
     }

}
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BotMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BotMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it.. Just add a check for HTTP status code 404 in the `handleError` method. The current implementation returns 400 for all errors

Comment: Its not working for me. Does the CustomErrorController need an annotation?

Comment: can you please check it, the above solution works for me and verified it @Luke101

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something, especially with the bounty on this.  Isn't this really easy?  I've done something like this in the past:

```
@Controller
class foo {
    @GetMapping("**")
    public static ResponseEntity blah() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}
```

Since Spring prioritizes the longest mapping that matches a particular path, this only wins if nothing else matches.

Go ahead...point out what I'm missing please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do this. This is a very bad practice. I would recommend changing the design. If you want to do this, there are a couple of things you can do to achieve this-

1. Change your configs at the load balancer/server level, if you use any(like nginx). This would be the recommended approach as you would not want such changes to be a part of your codebase. Codebase should only contain Business Logic, Business Rules, Domain Logic etc.
2. Create an interceptor in your spring boot codebase and return the 400 response from there if the controller mapping is not found. Take help from here- [Spring: Checking if given endpoint exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585033/spring-checking-if-given-endpoint-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class and override the `handleNoHandlerFoundException` to adjust it to return as bad request.

Something like

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

 @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(final NoHandlerFoundException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
      HttpStatus newStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
      return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, newStatus, request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just code like this in your controller, the `HttpServletResponse` will be autowired :

```java
     @RequestMapping("/page")
     public String page(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
         if(doSomeThing()){
             return "success";
         } else {
             response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),"Message:400");
             return "";
         }
     }
```